# Is there a way to send a completed build from a GitHub Action to a release?

Tags: github, github-actions, release-management

I would like to push a build that was completed on a GitHub action workflow using this code:

```
name: Build
on: [pull_request, push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build the app
        run: ./gradlew build
```

Currently this works for building the app and updating a status badge, but I would like the apk file from this build to be pushed directly as a pre-release. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

If you want to make a GitHub release containing the file, there are a lot of GitHub actions. This action - [automatic-releases](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/automatic-releases), I think can do the work for you.

> This action simplifies the GitHub release process by automatically uploading assets, generating changelogs, handling pre-releases, and so on.

As I see you use Gradle, you can check the GitHub docs for [publishing-java-packages-with-gradle](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/publishing-java-packages-with-gradle)